# How to get position of inkml data from OneNote API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

I am able to retrieve a page with inkML data from OneNote API as described here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/blogs/onenote-ink-beta-apis/

When the page is retrieved via the api (page data and inkML data).
How do I know the X, Y position (see image) of the inkml data to present it in relation to the textual data from that page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way you have drawn the page is correct. The info  retrieved from the API is in the format
`<inkml:trace xml:id="st0" contextRef="#ctxCoordinatesWithPressure" brushRef="#br0">1423 7569 3456,x,y,F,etc.` 
Where x and y co-ordinates have their origin from the top left of the page (f is pressure).
Check the following [InkMLjs github page](https://github.com/microsoft/InkMLjs/) for an example implementation dragdrop.html + inkml.js. Just save your retrieved (or generated) InkML data and drop it into the dragdrop.html webpage to display it.